# How to remove an element attribute using Selenium and C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

below is the chunk of html from which i want "disabled="disabled"" deleted and close the dev tools window. iam using selenium-webdriver with c#. 
Thank you.

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="javascript:;" id="SendRFQ" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Processing..." disabled="disabled" onclick="return SubmitRequisitionData(&quot;Submitted&quot;)">Click to Submit</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try below code to remove attribute from element

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("document.querySelector('a.btn.btn-success').removeAttribute('disabled')");
```

P.S. Note that real user will not modify HTML DOM to make link enabled, so if you need your script to simulate user-like behavior you should find another approach to make element enabled...

Answer (score 2):

To delete/remove the *attribute* and it's *value* of **`disabled="disabled"`** as the element is [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element you need to use *WebDriverwait* for the *element to be visible* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `PartialLinkText`:

  ```
  IWebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.PartialLinkText("Click to Submit")));
  ((IJavascriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('disabled')", element);
  ```
- Using `CssSelector`:

  ```
  IWebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("a.btn.btn-success#SendRFQ")));
  ((IJavascriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('disabled')", element);
  ```
- Using `XPath`:

  ```
  IWebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//a[@class='btn btn-success' and @id='SendRFQ']")));
  ((IJavascriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('disabled')", element);
  ```