# How to get inline style set dynamically using selenium? getAttribute('style') always returns ""

Tags: html, css, selenium, getattribute

How can I get style added dynamically using selenium? `GetAttribute('style')` always returns "". The `webElement` I am trying to get `border-color` property does not have `style` attribute set on initial page load. Later on, after I enter a value in another textbox and click on a button, the textbox I am interested in initially does not have a style assigned to it, based on the response I get after clicking the button, either red or green border is added based on whether a member is active or not.

Unfortunately, I am not able to get the color of the border which was added dynamically using `GetAttribute('style')`, because it always returns "".

Also, `GetAttribute('value')` returns always one text

> Member is not active

which I cannot find in the page source, although textbox is displaying Member is eligible. The text value is set based on the response.

I have been struggling with this problem for a couple of days without success.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="member-status" placeholder="Member CardID Status" disabled="" style="border-color: red; border-style: solid; border-width: 5px;">
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove `disabled` attribute?

Comment: Is it possible to remove attributes from a web page using Selenium? I am using Selenium to scrape data from web sites' pages and use the scraped data in my C# application.

Comment: As mentioned in this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376933/how-to-remove-an-element-attribute-using-selenium-and-c), you need to use `WebDriverwait` for the element to be visible.


For example: `IWebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.PartialLinkText("Click to Submit")));
((IJavascriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('disabled')", element);`

Comment: I managed to remove disabled and got the following result in C# command window {Element (id = 0.0863928211799887-4)}
    Coordinates: {OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteCoordinates}
    Displayed: true
    Enabled: true
    Id: "0.0863928211799887-4"
    Location: {X = 64 Y = 372}
    LocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView: {X = 63 Y = 371}
    Selected: false
    Size: {Width = 672 Height = 34}
    TagName: "input"
    Text: ""
    WrappedDriver: {OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver} but style attibute is still ""

Comment: I tried HTML agility pack as follows but the same result, no trace of style attribute              var doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.LoadHtml(driver.PageSource);
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@id=\"member-status\"]");
string attrib = node.Attributes.Where(x => x.Name == "style").Select(x => x.Value).SingleOrDefault();