# How to fix js to delete "autocompletee= off"?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

I don't know how to use selenium to delete `autocomplete = off`

This is raw code

> input type=text id=searchInput    **autocomplete = off**
> placeholder="输入城市名称、拼音查询天气"><span class=input-group-addon
> id=indexSearchButton style="background-color: transparent;cursor:
> pointer;height: 40px;line-height: 40px;padding: 0 12px

Answer (score 1):

Remove the attribute?

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("document.querySelector('a.btn.btn-success').removeAttribute('autocomplete ')");
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53377307/18208924